# Find all positive integers $n$ such that sum of digits of $2^n$ is equal to $n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For example, $2^5=32$ and $3+2=5$. Similarly, it can be shown that it works for $2^{70}$. 
Using basic results in modular arithmetic, one can show that $n$ has to be either of the form $18k+5$ or $18k+16$, where $k$ is non-negative integer. The two examples satisfy the form (for $k=0$ and $k=3$) but I was not able to find other examples. 
I do know that $2^n$ has $\left \lfloor    n\cdot \log_{10}2\right \rfloor+1$ digits which, coupled with the fact that average digit value is $4.5$, implies that the average digit sum is about $1.35n$. Clearly, this is much larger than $n$ (for large $n$) so it may be that no other $n$ satisfies the question I posed.

Any ideas how to proceed?

Comment: I have no idea if this is hard enough for number theory so I have tagged it with elementary number theory. I have also found the sequence here http://oeis.org/A001370 .

Comment: The only $n\le 100000$ are $5$ and $70$.

Comment: You analysis seems right. The sum seems to oscillate closely around $1.35n$.

Comment: Thanks! Have you checked it or is this sourced from somewhere?

Comment: I've run a program.

Comment: OEIS says "it is believed that $a(n) \sim n \cdot (9/2)\log_{10}2$, but this is an open problem."

Comment: The same analysis seems to work for other bases, except $10$, of course.

Comment: I think this one might be extremely difficult to prove in any base that is not a power of $2$.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the heuristic considerations:

Suppose for each positive integer $n$ you took $c n$ iid random variables $X_i(n)$ (where $4.5 c > 1$), each having values $0,\ldots,9$ with equal probability, and let $S_n$ be their sum.  According to Cramer's Theorem from the theory of
Large Deviations, $\log P(S(n) \le n)$ is asymptotic to a negative constant times $n$ (where the constant can be computed, but I won't bother).  In particular $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(S(n) \le n) < \infty$.
Then, according to Borel-Cantelli, almost surely only finitely many of the
events $S_n \le n$ occur.  With a bit more work you can estimate the expected number of occurrences.

Of course the digits of powers of $2$ are not really random, but it's quite reasonable to expect, on this basis, that there are only finitely many $n$ for which the sum of the digits of $2^n$ is at most $n$.

Comment: I see the idea but I have this question: where is the "breaking point" in the following sense: using this argument we can start making digit sum closer to the average and keep increasing number of solutions. Surely, eventually we have to have infinite number of solutions. Does this happen when the summation you mention become infinite? I ask this because it seems to me that it is key to compute P's AND show their sum is finite.

Comment: The other part of the Borel-Cantelli lemma says that if $E_n$ are **independent** events with $\sum_n P(E_n) = \infty$, then almost surely infinitely many of them occur.

Comment: Benford's law (applicable for leading digit of $2^n$) gives that digits are not uniformly distributed for the leading digit. Later digits, while getting close to uniform, are not exactly uniformly distributed. Paper I found by T. Hill mentioned also that digits are NOT independently distributed. But let's say that we can somehow overcome these issues and apply some version of Cramer's theorem which does not need IID assumption to show that sum you mention is finite. How do we then know where these finite cases are (i.e. how do we know $n=70$ is the last case?)

Comment: We don't.  The most we can do is estimate the expected number of additional cases.

Comment: BTW you might also mention some reasons the digits are not independent: their sum mod 9 is known, as is their alternating sum mod 11.

Comment: General version of Benford's Law - for example, probability that the second digit is 2 is not the the same as the probability that the second digit is 2 given that the first digit is 1.

Comment: Yes, but the effect on most of the digits is very small.

Comment: Yes, you are right. See for example http://statweb.stanford.edu/~cgates/PERSI/papers/digits.pdf (Theorem 5). There is probably approach to neglect this small dependence and use modified Cramer's Theorem. Unfortunately, I don't know much about it. Back to your previous comment: how do we estimate the number of additional cases?

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but I wanted to share a graph of the sum of digits $a(n)$ divided by $n$. As can be seen below, it clusters nicely around $1.35n$, which confirms your analysis.

[OEIS](http://oeis.org/A001370) says "it is believed that $a(n) \sim n \cdot (9/2)\log_{10}2$, but this is an open problem". Of course, you don't need this in full to prove what you want, just that $a(n) > 1.2 n$ (for instance) for $n>70$.

$\hbox{}\quad$
[image]

Comment: I do have have an idea how to derive the probability of $1.35\cdot n$ digit number having sum of digits equal to $n$ but I don't want to proceed since I am not sure what to do if I have that probability. Essentially, this probability will (I expect) approach $0$ exponentially (in $n$) but how to use that to confirm that there are no other solutions?